# Delphi: How to register the ZLibCompression filter in a datasnap-xe server

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, datasnap

**PROBLEM:**

I'm using a ZLibCompression filter in DataSnap-XE server.

The client always gives the follow error the message:

*"Borland.Data.TDBXError:Communication filter ZLibCompression is not registered. Filter class needs to be registered in order to communicate with the server"*

**QUESTION: 1**

How do I register ZLibCompression filter ?

**EDIT**

**QUESTION: 2**

How do I get the Datasnap-Connection in the DataExplorer to link to this server?

Comment: the error message really should add `'... - to solve this problem, try to add <unit name> to your project'` (as the DocWiki page is not helpful wrg to the unit name too)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add the `DbxCompressionFilter` unit to the uses clause of the client (as also discussed in my Delphi XE DataSnap courseware manual, and I believe it's also in the old DataSnap white paper that I wrote last year).

The DbxCompressionFilter unit already contains the following code:

```
initialization
  TTransportFilterFactory.RegisterFilter(TTransportCompressionFilter);

finalization
  TTransportFilterFactory.UnregisterFilter(TTransportCompressionFilter);

end.
```

Answer (score 4):

Call the TTransportFilterFactory.RegisterFilter method in order to register a filter.

Documentation ([Filtering DataSnap](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Filtering_DataSnap_Byte_Stream)) says:

> A filter needs to be registered with the TTransportFilterFactory singleton. The recommended way to register a filter is through the unit initialization and finalization sections, but it can be coded through an initialization phase in the user's application.
>
> Below is the code snippet registering the compression filter available out of the box:

```
initialization
  TTransportFilterFactory.RegisterFilter(TTransportCompressionFilter);

finalization
  TTransportFilterFactory.UnregisterFilter(TTransportCompressionFilter);
```

Change TTansportcompressionFilter for the name of the class you're using to filter.